# Add Standalone ASP.Net Application Into Existing ASP.Net Website - not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have an asp.net '4.5' site (Orion Solarwinds) and I would like to add functionality. This can be done with a virtual directory, but adding anything to that folder will cause a recompile and interrupt service to the user. 
It should be possible(and done it many times before) to 'just' add a  application. So I should be able to use a separate application pool. 
BUT what happens is that even with a index.html file in an empty application with a web.config in there, it still seems to inherit from the host webconfig. Thus this is not a Standalone ASP.Net Application in an existing website. I have tried to decouple this basic application - no joy. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the screenshot of IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using inheritInChildApplication by wrapping sections you don't want to inherit in host webconfig with this:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

There's more details [in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453712/add-standalone-asp-net-application-into-existing-asp-net-website-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, there were a lot of sections to isolate. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, there were a lot of sections to isolate. 
Still have a problem of wanting DLL from the parent BIN folder, so copying that to the new folder works, but feels like cheating :(
Thanks again.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx